# Check if username exists in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Been digging around for a solution but none for Meteor. If any, please let me know. I want to check if a username is already taken.

I understand that this only works on the server side only:

```
u = Accounts.findUserByUsername('foo');
console.log(u.username); #=> foo
```

I cant get my head around their pub/sub as I can only see information based on the current user. Is meteor saying that what I want is not possible?

When a user is filling out their details upon registration, I want them to be alerted (as they type) if the username they are using is already taken. But that logic I can easily code but need to know how to talk to the server to tell me the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a Meteor method for that:

```
Meteor.methods({
  doesUserExist(name) {
    return Accounts.findUserByUsername(name) != null;
  }
});
```

Note that you have to define this method on the server but not on the client (e.g., by defining it in a file inside the *server* directory). That way Meteor won't try to simulate it on the client (which would fail because `Accounts.findUserByUsername` is not defined there).

Call the method as the user types:

```
Meteor.call('doesUserExist', name, function(error, result) {
  // `result` is true if the user exists.
});
```

Comment: Ok. Ill give this a go and report later. Thanks